# Firebase client-side fan-out performance

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

for my new app i use this method

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html

i think that is a good method for a person that have a number of followers less than 1 million. i try and up to this number is fine. but for person that have 10kk
of followers the client get in crash because you get a big array of 10kk followers and short it to create another big array of 10kk of path activities.

I just wanted to point out this point, i think that this is a solution that work only with app that have a few numbers of users. finally We're forced to use server-side solutions. and this is bad for the general app efficency

Comment: For a user with that number of followers you should indeed probably run the fan-out in a server-side process. Not necessarily because the app would crash, but because of bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

would be a nice feature a function that allow this thing by firebase side with less cost in the client side. i think a feature like this. i make an example in javascript
                                                                             `var obj = { created: time }                                                                                var path = "FollowersActivity/uid/"                                                                                           var followers = 'root.child("Followers").child("uid").val()'                         function massSaved(obj, path, followers)`

by firebase server side the server get all childs by "followers" path and by foreach cycle append every follower name at the "path" string and save all objects. in this mode the client send only fews strings at firebase server without get all followers and make other big array of activity. probably my example not work because i not know the firebase infrastructure but is only an example to suggest an idea to conclude these operations entirely on the server side